# Oacle SQL : command not executing properly

Tags: sql, oracle

I am executing following query in oracle SQL developer

```
SELECT PROPERTYNO FROM VIEWING WHERE COMMENTS IS NOT NULL
UNION (SELECT PROPERTYNO FROM PROPERTYFORRENT MINUS SELECT PROPERTYNO FROM VIEWING);
```

but I am getting below error, though I feel my query is correct. can anyone suggest me what's wrong in my query?

```
SELECT PROPERTYNO FROM VIEWING WHERE COMMENTS IS NOT NULL
UNION (SELECT PROPERTYNO FROM PROPERTYFORRENT MINUS SELECT PROPERTYNO FROM VIEWING)
Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Do you have any other statements above this in the same script that might not be ended? I don't see a syntax problem in this specific statement.

Comment: @HepC You are right. my statement above this doesn't ended properly

Comment: Do the Views PROPERTYFORRENT and VIEWING have ORDER BY clauses in them? If that's the case - that might be your problem, because I see none in the actual query. If PROPERTYNO was of different type in both the views it would have given you ORA-01790.